# DRF serialize and save model with user FK

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

**models.py**

```
class UserContentItem(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserContentItemView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        data['owner'] = request.user.id
        serializer = UserContentItemSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserContentItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserContentItem
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'created_date')
```

I am building an API with Django Rest Framework and simple jwt. I want to allow authenticated users to POST a new `UserContentItem` that has a FK dependency on the `User` but the `User` is not part of the POST payload. The only way I've been able to figure out how to do this is as above, adding the `request.user.id` to the request data before passing it to the serializer. Is there a better way to serialize the `UserContentItem` and achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try like this using [CurrentUserDefault](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```
class UserContentItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, 
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserContentItem
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'created_date')
```

And in view, pass request as context to serializer:

```
serializer = UserContentItemSerializer(data=data,context={'request':request})
```

Also you don't need to pass user id with `data`.

Comment: I like this approach, however, I am getting an error: 
`self.user = serializer_field.context['request'].user
KeyError: 'request'`.   Do I need to add a param `context` to `def post(self, request):` ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. Please have a look. FYI: in [GenericViews](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), request is passed to serializer automatically through context. @Carter

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good even you can follow these

```
serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```